# DataTables TableTools export buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, tabletools

Using the code below, I can get the `TableTools` buttons to show up on the page, style correctly, and even change the mouse icon on the `mouseover` event, however the export function is not working. When I click on the button, nothing happens. Don't even get an error message.

The `DataTable` the `TableTools` plugin is working on does not exist on the page prior to the user hitting a "Search" button. Once this is done an Ajax call will pull the relevant data and create the `DataTable`. Again, this part of the program works fine, however when I click on the "Export" buttons (CSV, Excel, PDF)... nothing happens.

**jQuery**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("PensgcReport", "Home")',
        data: { inputArray: inputArray },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            //Unpack return object into 2D array
            var array = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                var tempArray = [];
                $.each(value, function(key, value) {
                    tempArray.push(value);
                });
                array.push(tempArray);
            });

            console.log(array);
            $('#ReportTable').dataTable({
                "bDestroy" : true,
                "aaData": array,
                "aoColumns": headers,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Filter results:"
                },
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "tableTools": {
                    "sSwfPath": "Content/media/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                    "aButtons": 
                    [
                            {
                                'sExtends': 'csv',
                                "sFileName": "PENSGC_Report_" + new Date() + ".csv",
                                'mColumns': [0, 1]
                            },
                            {
                                'sExtends': 'xls',
                                "sFileName": "PENSGC_Report_" + new Date() + ".xls",
                                'mColumns': [0, 1]
                            },
                            {
                                'sExtends': 'pdf',
                                "sFileName": "PENSGC_Report_" + new Date() + ".pdf",
                                'mColumns': [0, 1]
                            },
                    ]
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

**HTML**

This is the rendered HTML when the page loads (nothing special)

```
    <table id="ReportTable" class="pretty">

    </table>
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: It seems to be linking / addressing to .swf file. Can you test changing "sSwfPath" with full url instead of relative url?

Comment: Changed to `http://localhost:56789/Content/media/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` and still getting the same result

Comment: Your environment is Unix based? Probably permissions?

Comment: Just running this in Visual Studio on a Windows 7 machine. You believe the problem is the accessibility of the `.swf` file?

Comment: I once had the same problem. This happened using Datatables 1.8 and I had to download an extra plugin called TableTools and point to these .swf files and it worked. In html also I had to include <script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/TableTools.js"></script>. What version are you using?

Comment: probably these other explanations with similar issue may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206345/tabletools-plugin-export-buttons-are-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Change the swf path to:

```
"sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var table = $('#mytable').dataTable({ YOUR OPTIONS});
       var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
               "buttons": ["copy",
                                  "csv",
                                  "xls",
                                  "pdf",{ "type": "print", "buttonText": "Print me!" } ],
                                  "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" });
           $(tableTools.fnContainer()).prependTo('#mytable_wrapper');
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and provide an explanation with the code.